# Drop shadow for a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

**Background:** I have a `DropShadowFrameLayout` in my app, which is a container used just to draw a drop shadow over it's child views. Like a shadow on top and bottom of a `ListView`, you know.

It is based on this article: http://proandroiddev.blogspot.ru/2012/01/android-design-tip-drop-shadows-on.html

Cyril Mottier also suggests the same approach: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/06/08/the-making-of-prixing-3-polishing-the-sliding-app-menu/

It simply overrides `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` to draw a shadow bitmap over it's children.

I have a `VerticalViewPager` (https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) inside of a `DropShadowFrameLayout`, and the problem is that it deepens the view hierarchy (which is already complex), causing scrolling glitches.

**What I tried:** I decided to get rid of that `DropShadowFrameLayout` by moving shadow-drawing code directly to `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` of a `ViewPager`. And the problem here is that `ViewPager` **draws shadow only on the one initially visible child, and when I scroll it, the shadow moves along with it.** Of course this is not the behavior I expect, because shadows must be still while the child views move.

This method worked well with a `ListView`.

**The question is:** how do I apply this method to a `ViewPager`? Or is there another way of doing this, which is equal performance-wise? Or, at least, why does the `ViewPager` behave this way?

Comment: so you say that ViewPager.dispatchDraw is called only once ???

Comment: No, it's called many times, but somewhy the shadow is drawn at the same place (like it's drawn in the child, not above it)

Comment: translate the canvas by getScrolllX/Y

Comment: yep, already figured that, your first comment was enlightening) thank you

Comment: btw it seems like scrolling lag was caused by creating bitmap every time in the dispatchDraw, and not by hierarchy depth. should have guessed...

Comment: next tine you can use traceview to find out bottlenecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that shadows in `DropShadowFrameLayout` were always drawn at the fixed position:

`private Rect getDropShadowArea(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bm) {
   return new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
 }`

`ViewPager` turned out to use his inner coordinates, so the solution was to adjust this method to be aware of current scroll position of `ViewPager` (I use Y instead of X because I actually use `VerticalViewPager`, but the principle is the same for both):

`private Rect getDropShadowArea(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bm) {
   return new Rect(0, getScrollY(), canvas.getWidth(),
                   getScrollY() + bm.getHeight());
 }`

Or you can just translate the `canvas` by `getScrollY()` before drawing, if you like (thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)).

Also the scrolling lag was (partly) caused by getting the `Bitmap` every time in the `dispatchDraw()`.